# android mediaplayer is playing multiple instances from one player

Tags: android, media-player

so im trying to make a sound play through android. ive created a mediaplayer  like this

```
MediaPlayer player; (outside onCreate())
player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.theninth); (inside onCreate())
```

and then i reference this player throughout the Activity. .start() on shake. .pause onclick etc.. it looks like this

```
if(mag >= 500) {
    if(!started) {
        mainView.setText(R.string.waitforit);
        player.start();
        started = true;
        if(doThisOnce) {
            timer.schedule(changeText, 26000);
            doThisOnce = false;
        }
    }
    player.setVolume((float)(2*mag/3.0),(float)(2*mag/3.0));
}
```

and

```
public void stopAudio(View v) {
    mainView.setText(R.string.shakeme);
    player.pause();
    started = false;
}
```

and so the problem is the player doesnt pause when i tap the screen, instead it goes to the starting text of hte app, and and its like i reloaded the entire app, and i can shake it and then another intance of the same file from the same player will start playing.. what do?

Comment: When you shake the phone there's a good chance you're changing orientation (from portrait to landscape). A change in orientation is considered a change in `configuration` and the `Activity` will be destroyed and recreated. You don't really give enough information to go on but I'm guessing that's what is happening. Look at handling `configuration` changes yourself.

Comment: yes it seems as though changing the orientation to/from landscape resets the app, so adding android:configChanges="orientation" to the manifest fixed everything.. thank you.